# How to efficiently match between arrays in a Mongo document and that in query criteria?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

**Problem Description:**

I want to retrieve all documents that are tagged with an array of String values if even one of those string values is contained in an array passed in by the client.

**Code:**

Post Schema:

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    post: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      maxlength: [3000, "A post should be less than 3000 characters"],
      unique: false,
    },
    details: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      maxlength: [4000, "An author may add additional detail if they wish."],
    },
    tags: {
      type: [String],
      required: false,
    },
   ...
```

Sample Post document:

```
  {
    "_id": "5d713995b721c3bb38c1f5d0",
    "user": "5c8a1d5b0190b214360dc031",
    "post": "The best composer of all time was Mozart",
    "details": "Some details here",
    "tags": ["music", "composers", "Mozart"],
  }
```

I'm open to testing all solutions for returning the result.  A successful solution would be for the query to return all Post documents if even one tag matches at least one tag in the search criteria array.

In addition, the solution should be efficient and low-cost from a Mongo DB standpoint, as it may be a frequent query.

(In SQL, there may be variants to this solution involving commands that do different things in the Mongo world; while I could do this in SQL fairly easily, I'm wondering if Mongo has an equivalently straight-forward approach for this matching.)

Thus far I've tried various approaches and consulted the official mongo docs here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/

Answer (score 2):

Test yourself: https://mongoplayground.net/p/rwFf8oiQTqb

Using `find`:

```
db.collection.find({tags: {$in: ["music", "movies"]}})
```

Using `aggregate`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "tags": {
        "$in": [
          "music",
          "movies"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5d713995b721c3bb38c1f5d0",
    "details": "Some details here",
    "post": "The best composer of all time was Mozart",
    "tags": [
      "music",
      "composers",
      "Mozart"
    ],
    "user": "5c8a1d5b0190b214360dc031"
  }
]
```

Comment: That definitely works; I'm wondering about the 'cost' of running aggregates in frequent searches, but so far, this seems like the most efficient solution.  I'm interested in seeing other approaches as well if there are any.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated with a `find` approach too.